# php DOMdocument how to select multiple tag elements?

Tags: php

I have the following code below

```
  $Dom = new DOMDocument;
  @$Dom->loadHTML("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><body>$body</body>");
  $links = $Dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
  $arr = array();
  foreach ($links as $link) {
    if ($link->attributes[0]->name == 'href' && $link->attributes[0]->value != '#') {
      $link->attributes[0]->value = 'changed.com';
    }
  }
```

i want to also add the button tag something like this `$Dom->getElementsByTagName('a,button');`

Comment: You can't do that. It's not like CSS selectors, you can't select multiple things at the same time.

Comment: Just do another selection: `$buttons = ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DOMXPath::query()` or extends `DOMElement` and register by `DOMDocument::registerNodeClass()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multiple selector using [XPath](https://php.net/domxpath) : `$xpath->query('//a | //button')`.

```php
// HTML sample 
$body = '<p><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">another</a><button>button</button><i>some text</i></p>';

// Load and query
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><body>$body</body>");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodelist = $xpath->query('//a | //button');

// Display information
echo "Length is : " . $nodelist->length, PHP_EOL;
foreach ($nodelist as $index => $node) {
    echo "- Node $index is $node->nodeName" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
Length is : 3
Node 0 is a
Node 1 is a
Node 2 is button
```

See also a [live demo (3v4l.org)](https://3v4l.org/umYVC).